# Доступ к функционалу скрипта по ip

Tags: ip, php

Здравствуйте!
Задача:
Вывести таблицу с данным, где проставляется время и дата - работает
Доступ по ip (из массива) к правке каждой строки - не могу понять как сделать. Сейчас работает правка одной строки. Код не мой, поэтому прошу помочь разобраться куда запихать цикл, чтобы редактировались определенные строки разрешенные определенному ip. Ниже приведен код:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./alexdm.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./alexdm.js"></script>
</head>

<?php

/*подключение к БД */

$rep_header='Заголовок';
$aacc=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');

$config = array();
include_once('./массив ip адрисов c привязкой кодов.php');

/*берем ip пользователя
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
/*сравниваем ip пользователя с ip из массива
$tSRS_by_ip = getSubnetCodeByIP_cp1251($user_ip,$config['SubnetCodes']);

$tSRS = (isset($_POST['tSRS'])) ? $_POST['tSRS'] : $tSRS_by_ip;

$date1 = (isset($_GET['date1'])) ? $_GET['date1'] : '';
$date1 = (($date1!='')&&(checkdate(substr($date1,3,2),substr($date1,0,2),substr($date1,6,4)))&&(substr($date1,6,4)>=2012)&&(substr($date1,6,4)<=strftime('%Y',time()))) ? $date1 : '';
$acc = (isset($_GET['acc'])) ? $_GET['acc'] : '';
$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';

$xls= (isset($_POST['xls'])) ? $_POST['xls'] : false;

echo '<body onload="preload_page()">';
if ($xls) {
  $export_file = "rep.xls"; 
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1 
  header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
  header ("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: windows-1251');
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;'); // This should work for IE & Opera
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$export_file.'"');
} else {
  echo '<div id="load">'.$instance.'<br>Формирование отчета<br>"'.$rep_header.'" за '.$date1.'<br><div id="countup"></div></div>';
  ob_flush(); flush();
}
echo '<div id="total">';

echo '
<ul id="mainNav">
  <li><span onclick="ShowDiv(1);"></span></li>
</ul>';

if ($conn = @oci_connect($user, $pass, $instance)) {

  if ($acc!='') {
    switch ($action) {
      case 'del': 
        $sqltext3="delete from wer".$wer."00_VIP_REP where DATE_R=to_date(:DATE1,'dd.mm.yyyy') and SRS=:SRS and ACC=:ACC";
        break;
      case 'ins':
        $sqltext3="
          merge into wer".$wer."00_VIP_REP d
          using (select to_date(:DATE1,'dd.mm.yyyy') DATE_R,:SRS SRS,:ACC ACC from dual) o 
          on (d.DATE_R=o.DATE_R and d.SRS=o.SRS and d.ACC=o.ACC)
          when not matched then insert (d.DATE_R,d.SRS,d.ACC) values (to_date(:DATE1,'dd.mm.yyyy'),:SRS,:ACC)";
        break;
    }
    $sql3 = OCIParse($conn, $sqltext3);
    oci_bind_by_name($sql3, ":DATE1", $date1);
    oci_bind_by_name($sql3, ":SRS", $tSRS);
    oci_bind_by_name($sql3, ":ACC", $acc);
    OCI_Execute($sql3);
    OCI_Commit($conn);
  }

  if ($date1=='') {
    $sqltext2="
      SELECT to_char(TRADING_DATE,'dd.mm.yyyy') TRADING_DATE FROM  (
      SELECT TRADING_DATE FROM XXT_GL_TRADING_DAYS_SYS_V WHERE TRADING_DATE<trunc(SYSDATE)
        order by TRADING_DATE desc
      ) WHERE ROWNUM=1";
    $sql2 = OCIParse($conn, $sqltext2);
     OCI_Execute($sql2);
    if (OCIFetch($sql2)) {
      $date1=oci_result($sql2,1);
    }
  }

  $sqltext1="SELECT TO_CHAR(TSTAMP,'DD-mm   HH24:MI:SS') TSTAMP FROM web".$web."00_VIP_REP WHERE DATE_R=TO_DATE(:DATE1,'dd.mm.yy') AND SRS=:SRS AND ACC=:ACC";
  $sql1 = OCIParse($conn, $sqltext1);

  $sqltext="SELECT CODE AS TSRS FROM apps.xxt_rd_ft_ext_v
    WHERE CODE LIKE '".$web."%' and CODE<>'".$web."00' and STATUS_CODE='801'
    ORDER BY CODE ";
  $sql = OCIParse($conn, $sqltext);
  OCI_Execute($sql);

  echo '<table class="repheader" width="100%">'.
    '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="arep.php" method="get" name="rep"> 
    <th colspan="10" class="postbody" width="100%">'
    .$rep_header.' за '.$date1.'&nbsp;'.
    '<input type="datetime-local" name="date1" value="'.$date1.'" size="8">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Обновить"></form>
    </table>';

  echo '<table class="forumline" width="100%">';
  $ncols = oci_num_fields($sql);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $ncols; $i++) {
    $column_name  = oci_field_name($sql, $i);
    $column_type  = oci_field_type($sql, $i);
    $column_size  = oci_field_size($sql, $i);
    echo '<th class="thTop">'.$column_name;
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($aacc); $i++) {
    $column_name  = $aacc[$i];
    echo '<th class="thTop">'.$column_name;
  }
  $k=1;
  while (OCIFetch($sql)) {
    $ctSRS=oci_result($sql,1);

    $rowclass=(($k % 2)==0) ? 'row1' : 'row2';
    $rowclass=($ctSRS==$tSRS)?'row5':$rowclass;
    echo '<tr>';

    echo '<td align="left" valign="top" class="'.$rowclass.'"><span class="postbody">&nbsp;'.$ctSRS.'</span></td>';

    foreach ($aacc as $val) {
      oci_bind_by_name($sql1, ":DATE1", $date1);
      oci_bind_by_name($sql1, ":SRS", oci_result($sql, 1));
      oci_bind_by_name($sql1, ":ACC", $val);
      OCI_Execute($sql1);
      echo '<td align="left" valign="top" class="'.$rowclass.'"><span class="postbody">';
      $lFetch=OCIFetch($sql1);
      $res= ($lFetch) ? '&nbsp;'.oci_result($sql1, 1) : '&nbsp;';

      if ($ctSRS==$tSRS) {
        echo '<a href="./rep.php?date1='.$date1.'&acc='.$val
          .'&action='.(($lFetch)?'del':'ins').'" class="mainmenu">
          <img src="./'.(($lFetch)?'icon_mini_register.gif':'icon_mini_unregister.gif').'" 
          border="0" alt="Изменить" hspace="3" /></a>';
      }

      echo $res.'</span></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    $k++;
  }
  echo '</table>';

  oci_close($conn);
} else {
  $err = OCIError();
  echo 'Ошибка '.$err.' соединения с '.$instance.'<br>';
}
echo '</div>';
echo '<script>check_preload=1;</script>';

echo '</body></html>';
?>
```

массив ip адресов перечислены в другом файле.
Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы так сумбурно мысли выражаете )) Сами хоть понимаете, прочитав ваш вопрос, чего вы хотите?

А по поводу разграничения прав доступа, то обратите внимание на переменные `$tSRS` (возможно тут находится ключ - посмотрите, что возвращает `getSubnetCodeByIP_cp1251()`), `$acc` и строчки

```
oci_bind_by_name($sql3, ":SRS", $tSRS);
oci_bind_by_name($sql3, ":ACC", $acc);
```

Возможно, значение из `getSubnetCodeByIP_cp1251()` можно будет передавать в POST. Может пригодиться.